# Frame control load new copy of page

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with my WPF app. I use listbox with items which is pages name and frame with pages. I have few huge pages (near 20-25 MB in memory after loading) and when I switch between pages they doubled in memory for some time and all methods called twice. After some period it stops and begin work in normal way, but this affect on application behavior.

My question is: how to make pages not doubled in memory to avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

In this case better to create instance of the class explicit in code behind and then push to content property of the frame:

```
    MyClass my = new myClass();

    if (Frame1.Content == null)
    {
    Frame1.Content = my;
    }

    or
    if (Frame1.Content == null)
    {
    Frame1.Content = new MyClass();
    }
```

Also this will speed up loading of page.